# What is the disadvantage of adding custom field in post table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am a naive developer and just learning wordpress. I am going to use a custom post type in wordpress and having a question on whether I shall add some more custom fields in post table or I shall use post_meta table. People have been suggesting to use post_meta giving reference to wordpress design and upgrade issue but wouldn't performance be impacted if I add fields to post_meta when records grow in this table as it will be vertical growth.
Let's take an example that I am inserting 2 records in post table and I have 3 custom fields in meta so in post_meta 2 X 3 = 6 records will be created but if I add the custom field in post table it will be a horizontal growth and only records will be created in post table only.
Also how wordpress query data from both the tables? Does it use some view or join query? Some people suggest adding custom fields in post_meta as array to minimize no. of records but how will filtering happen if data is stored as an array.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? This seems like it would encourage opinions more than facts.

Comment: custom fields is saved in postmeta table. As a general rule (dont be fooled less row data is better btw) use postmeta as display info and use taxonomies where you intend to query the selection (it will have a url and is quicker than querying postmeta) and yes you should save postmeta as a array (unless you ever intend to query the information within, it will be serialized etc)

Comment: S O , no specific question, you are right it is more for opinion. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @David Thanks for your comment, I am taking care of things like you suggested but it was my concern where I have a listing page based on some custom fields filter and displaying more custom fields for each item.